# Allow communication between multiple python files

Tags: python, github, heroku

I am using github to store my code so heruku can use it

My question is how would I create two python scripts in github and have one store all the static data and allow the other script to read from the first script?

Also would I need to update my 'Procfile'. All I currently have in there is 'worker: python main.py' where main is one of my scripts. I would like to add another script called 'staticData.py'

Here is my github if it helps:
https://github.com/MeHead/lol_BOT

I'm fairly new to all this so a more explained answer would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is fairly simple:

In the `staticData.py` file you can store your variables simply like this:

```
a = 3
b = "Some text"
```

In some other file, lets say `main.py` you can then import them:

```
from staticData import a
from staticData import b
```

And then you can use them however you want.

P.S If you want to change the value of those variables in one function and then preserve this value in other functions, you have two ways:

Either import module and reference variables like this:

```
import staticData

staticData.a = 10
staticData.b = "changed the text"
```

or you can use `global` (especially if referencing from a function)

Comment: One would not need to make them `global` to allow changing them, just _always_ reference them through the module they're in. i.e. `import staticData as sd`, `sd.a = 42`, `print(sd.b)`, etc.

Comment: Yes, if he imports the whole module and references those variable by dot, then yes, no need for `global` here. I just think he only need to access them, not modify, so I've added this as a bonus, not a main part of the answer, so I didn't cover all the basis. Edited my answer

Comment: When I try: 'from staticData import a' it gives me the error NameError: name 'staticData' is not defined. But if I just do 'import staticData' it seems to work fine. Referencing it by eg. 'print(staticData.a) will return the value of staticData a correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Frynio: I think your edit is an improvement—no need encouraging folks to use global variables.